# Duplicate Window Bug

Tags: window-management, window-manager

In some applications e.g (Boinc or PlayOnLinux) I have the following bug:[image: bug]

Does anyone have any clue about this? I already searched for it but I did not found anything.

I can drag both windows to resize them. The inner or outer does not matter which one.

For anyone else having this issue please go here:
https://github.com/elementary/gala/issues/244

The user Sticcia has a good workaround:

Start an application with the issue like this:
`env Exec=env GTK_CSD=0 X`

Where `X` would be the application e.g. `playonlinux`.